# метатеги рендерятся не в том месте, yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть шаблон (layout), схему которого я привожу ниже и на "схеме" показываю, где стоят маркеры типа head() и прочих.

```
$this->beginPage();?>
<html>
<head>
...
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
...
</head>
<body>
$this->beginBody();
echo $this->render('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'layouts' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_header_index').PHP_EOL;
...
echo $content;
...
echo $this->render('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'layouts' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_footer').PHP_EOL;
$this->endBody();
</body>
</html>
$this->endPage()
```

В $content загружается собственно индексный action, вид которого следующий:

```
<?php

use common\helpers\AppHelper;
use common\models\SystemSetting;
use frontend\controllers\BasketController;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\validators\ValidationAsset;
use yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset;
use yii\widgets\LinkPager;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
use frontend\assets\CategoriesAsset;

$session = Yii::$app->session;
$request = Yii::$app->request;
$isHomepage = $this->params['isHomepage'] ?? false;
$basket = (int)BasketController::CartCount();
$domain = Yii::getAlias('@webfront');
$user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
$get = Yii::$app->request->get();

CategoriesAsset::register($this);
$this->registerJs('CatalogComponent.init()');

if(isset($get['productParam']))
    $params['productParam'] = $get['productParam'];
    else
        $params['productParam'] = [];
        if(isset($get['cat']))
            $params['cat'] = $get['cat'];
            else
                $params['cat'] = [];
                if(isset($get['provider']))
                    $params['provider'] = $get['provider'];
                    else
                        $params['provider'] = [];
                        if(isset($get['mod']))
                            $params['mod'] = $get['mod'];
                            else
                                $params['mod'] = '';
                            ?>

<?php 
$this->registerJsVar('THIS_URL',Url::toRoute(['categories/index', 'alias' => $mainCategory->alias]),$this::POS_END);
$this->registerJsVar('modView',$params['mod'],$this::POS_END);
$this->registerJsVar('mainCategory', $mainCategory->id, $this::POS_END);
$this->registerJsVar('listR', $listR, $this::POS_END);
?>

<div id="rec16558234" class="r t-rec r_showed r_anim" data-animationappear="on" data-record-type="754">
    <div class="t-container t754__container_mobile-grid">
        <div class="breadcrumb">
            <?= Html::a(Yii::$app->params['main_cat_name'], Url::toRoute(['categories/all-categories']));
                if(!empty($list)): foreach ($list as $cat):
                    echo Html::tag('span', ' → ');
                    echo Html::a($cat['name'], $cat->getUrl());
                endforeach; endif;
                echo Html::tag('span', ' → ');
                echo $mainCategory->name;
//                echo Html::a($mainCategory->name, Url::toRoute(['categories/index', 'alias' => $mainCategory->alias]));
            ?>
        </div>
            <?= $this->render('..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'layouts' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'filters',[
                'productParam' => $productParam,
                'productParams' => $productParams,
                'seoProps' => $seoProps,
                'providers' => $providers,
                'params' => $params,
                'full_count' => $full_count,
                'listR' => $listR,
                'mainCategory' => $mainCategory,
                'productProvider' => $productProvider,
                'title_name' => $title_name,
                'nameValue' => $nameValue,
            ]).PHP_EOL;?>
    </div>



    <?php 

    Pjax::begin([
        'id' => 'pjax-container',
        'formSelector' => 'filterByParams',
        'timeout' => 10000,
        'scrollTo' => 200,
    ]);
  <! ----------------- ВОТ ЭТО МЕСТО ------------------->
        $data['products'] = $products;
        $data['limit'] = $page_limit;
        $data['productProvider'] = $productProvider;
        echo frontend\controllers\ProductController::renderProductsPlate($data, $query);

    if (Yii::$app->request->get('page') == NULL) {
        echo Html::tag('div', $mainCategory->description, ['class' => 't-container t754__container_mobile-grid text__inner']);
    }else {
        if (Yii::$app->request->get('page') >= 1 AND Yii::$app->request->get('page') <= SystemSetting::getCountCategoryDescriptions() ){
            echo Html::tag('div', $mainCategory->{description.Yii::$app->request->get('page')}, ['class' => 't-container t754__container_mobile-grid text__inner']);
        }
    }
    Pjax::end();
    ?>
</div>
```

. В контроллере такой код:

```
        Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(['name'=>'description', 'content' => $mainCategory->meta_description], 'description');
        Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag(['name'=>'keywords', 'content' => $mainCategory->meta_keywords], 'keyword');
        Yii::$app->view->title  = (strlen($mainCategory->meta_title))? $mainCategory->meta_title:  $mainCategory->name;
```

Вставки "<----------------- ВОТ ЭТО МЕСТО ------------------->" в коде конечно же нету. Ею я показал место, где генерируется то, что должно быть сгенерировано в месте вызова  `<?php $this->head() ?>`, а именно:

```
<meta name="description" content="..............">
<meta name="keywords" content=".............">
<link href="/assets/8b07a5ae/css/bootstrap.css?v=1582991338" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/5f52a4ef/css/style.css?v=1582991338" rel="stylesheet" position="1">
<link href="/assets/5f52a4ef/css/megamenu.css?v=1582991338" rel="stylesheet" position="1">
<link href="/assets/5f52a4ef/icon/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?v=1582991338" rel="stylesheet" position="1">
<script src="/assets/328e8b1a/jquery.js?v=1582991338"></script>
<script src="/assets/9aebc51e/yii.js?v=1582991338"></script>
<script src="/assets/8b07a5ae/js/bootstrap.js?v=1582991338"></script>
<script src="/assets/5f52a4ef/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?v=1582991338"></script>
```

Грубо говоря, у меня вот эта вставка генериится посреди страницы. Собственно вопрос: почему в теле страницы у меня метатеги и некоторые скрипты сгененрировались, в произвольном месте? Как сделать так, чтоб метатеги вывелись там, где стоит маркер `<?php $this->head() ?>`?

Comment: думается мне место не там где указано, а после pjax-container

Comment: думается мне, вы об этот что-то знаете :) Я проверил, да, вы правы: блок генерируется после того как открылся pjax- контейнер. Почему так?

Comment: а только ли там теги находятся? в head точно ничего нет? не дублируется?

Comment: загляните в исходники Pjax виджета, в методе init все увидите, происходит очистка view  и пере-инициализация beginPage и т.д., но только если виджет рендерится когда был pjax запрос

Comment: кстати да, вы правы. Assets'ы задублировались, есть и в шапке и в этом месте. А метатеги (дескрипшен и кейворд) нет - вывелись только в этом месте. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: я закомментировал Pjax и теги остались там, где и были. Они не стали отображаться там, где должны. Дело не в Pjax

Answer (score 0):

При рендеринге одного из блоков использовался метод renderAjax(), а надо render(), т.к. renderAjax() рендерит именованный вид без шаблона, и **добавляет все зарегистрированные JS/CSS скрипты и стили**.